# Not sure what to synchronize with multi-threaded requests via URLConnection

Tags: java, multithreading, outputstream, urlconnection

My question is, since I'm creating multiple threads to send unique requests to the same OutputStream, which variables I only need to create 1 reference of (or synchronize). My professor didn't cover URLConnections.

When I only run 1 thread, it works fine, but multiple threads only produce output for the first.

Help is greatly appreciated.

=========================================================================

Inside the constructor of URLTest:

```
/*URL*/ link = new URL("url removed");
/*URLConnection*/ connect = link.openConnection();
connect.setDoOutput(true);
```

I'm executing this code inside URLTest:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadTest());
    /*ArrayList<Thread>*/ a.add(t);
    t.start();
}
```

run() inside ThreadTest implementing Runnable:

```
PrintWriter osw = new PrintWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
osw.write("query removed");
osw.close();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connect.getInputStream()));

String s;
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that a URLConnection had to be instantiated each time a new thread was created.